# What's the standard/best way to position a thumb to the left and text to the right?

Tags: css

What is the best/standard way of positioning an image to the left and have two fields of text to the right of it? Using floats? Positioning?

```
<li>
<a href=""> <img src=""THUMB HERE /> </a>
<a href=""> TITLE </a>
<span> META DATA </span>
</li>
```

This should be the result:

[image]

I'm not asking for a way to do it. I'm asking for the best way to do it with regards to cross browser compatibility and clean code.

Thanks!

Comment: It depends on whether or not you have a container, if it's taller than the elements, what browsers you need to support and if the thumbnail is larger than the text/container. Please post a jsFiddle with your use-case.

Comment: The container in this case is a li without height. The title and meta should always be on one line so they don't expand the li more than the thumb has already done. All modern browsers + ie8.

Comment: I m not sure about your requirement exactly but check this link, it might help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12635007/difference-between-float-and-align-property-in-css

Answer (score 0):

Using floats.

```
<li>
<div style="float:left">
<a href=""> <img src=""THUMB HERE /> </a>
</div>
<div style="float:left;padding-left:10px">
<a href=""> TITLE </a>
<span> META DATA </span>
</div>
<div style="clear:both">
</div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

The obvious solution would be floats:

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SO_AMK/wA8dj/

CSS:

```
li { display: inline-block; }
/* Keep it from being full width, if you define a width, skip this. */
li span.left { float: left; }
li span.right { float: right; }
```

Browser screenshots: http://imageshack.us/g/1/9808161/

The screenshots are of FX11, Chrome 18, Safari 5.1 and IE 8 & 9. In IE 7 the inline-block breaks and it becomes full width.