# Cant float link to right in the footer?

Tags: html, css

I cant figure out why the `Back to top` link wont float to the right of the "footer area" which have a width of 960px. When I run my the code, the `back to top` link is in the middle of the footer. Down here is my code, do any one get why it wont work?

HTML:

```
            <div id="fotsd">

                <div id="fotl">
                    <h5> &copy something </h5>
                </div>

                <div id="fotr>
                    <p id="fotrb">Back to top</p>
                </div>
            </div>

        </footer>
```

CSS:

```
#fots{
background-color: #ebebeb;
width: 100%;
}
#fotsd{
height: 50px;
padding-top:10px;
padding-left 5px;
padding-right: 5px;
width: 960px;
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
#fotl{
width: 480px;
float: left;
font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}
#fotr{
width: 480px;
float: right;
}
```

Comment: Why on earth are you using paragraph tags for links in the first place??!?!

Comment: It works perfectly fine in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sz78vyqv/

Comment: @Diodeus i was testing if it worked with a <p> instead of link, but the same here.

Comment: @User8889 The back to top is to the right of the center, I want it to the to the right completely, like the "copyright air dzenky" but instad of left to the right.

Comment: You probably want `text-align:right` on the `p` tag

Comment: Aah ok. You should just add text-align:right

Comment: My point: yes, it works, but it is bad form and is un-semantic. It also breaks SEO.

Comment: @Diodeus I rewrote the code like this http://jsfiddle.net/sz78vyqv/1/ and it works perfect, what do you think?

Comment: Looks good, but you don't really need the P and B tags in the "fotsd" element since you can style "fotsd" directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were some errors in the code.  Plus, I added a red background to  to demonstrate the elements being aligned properly:

```
<footer>
    <div id="fotsd">
        <div id="fotl">
             <h5> &copy Air Dzenky 2014 </h5>
        </div>
        <div id="fotr">
            <p id="fotrb">Back to top</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jazztorbs/3rgufzf5/

Comment: Please describe your solution a little more. What did you change?

Answer (score 1):

Just add `text-align:right` into your CSS:

```
#fotr{
  width: 480px;
  float: right;
  text-align:right;
}
```

Comment: It will still not work, this time the "Back to top" is outside of the footer and under the footer. I dont know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

using text-align right should do the trick. here's a helpful thread as well:
[Difference between float and align property in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12635007/difference-between-float-and-align-property-in-css)