# Right aligning panelGrid nested inside another

Tags: css, jsf

I am having trouble structuring a `panelGrid` nested inside another panelGrid so that its contents (submit buttons) are right aligned and everything else in the container panelGrid is left aligned.  The panelGrid is part of a small form that only contains a single input field and it has only a single column:

```
<h:panelGrid id="containerGrid" columns="1" cellpadding="10">

    <h:outputText id="commentIntro" value="#{myBean.commentIntro}"/>

    <h:outputLabel for="comment" value="Comment:"/>
    <h:inputTextarea id="comment" title="Comment" value="#{myBean.comment}"/>

    <h:panelGrid id="nestedGrid" columns="2" cellpadding="10" columnClasses="rightAlign,rightAlign">

        <h:commandButton id="submit" value="Submit" actionListener="#{myBean.processSubmit}"/>

        <h:commandButton id="cancel" value="Cancel" actionListener="#{myBean.processCancel}"/>
    </h:panelGrid>

</h:panelGrid>
```

And here is the style:

```
.rightAlign {
    text-align:right;
}
```

The submit buttons keep showing left aligned nonetheless. How do I left align them?

Comment: Please do as @ced states: learn to use browser dev tools and basic html and css. There is nothing jsf in this question.

Comment: I disagree because I am using JSF tags to generate HTML (`panelGrid` --> HTML table) as I am not using TDs and TRs, in which I would know where to situate my CSS specification.  I find the JSF way of assigning classes in a table convoluted with `rowClasses` and `columnClasses`.  That is why this is a JSF question.  In regard to your "learn your thing" arrogant comment, you should perhaps consider that there are different learning styles, top-down(whereby those it suits better first learn broad basics and then apply it) and bottom-up (whereby those who prefer it learn to do things and then...

Comment: use the bits and pieces to put together the big picture.  i belong in the latter category

Comment: It is not arrogant but a factual statement after spending a fair amount of time on StackOverflow and observing similar questions. Let me explain why. JSF is, as you state, an HTML generator. In the JSF spec you can read what the `rowClasses` and `columClasses` in general are for. In the browser developer tool you can see where they end up, and all that is there are TD's, TR's or DIV's etc... all just html. By knowing how css selectors work, css specificity etc, it is most of the time easy to style things, right align or whatever with the use of a browser developer tool.

Comment: So you develop like going to a car junkjard, buy spare parts and expect to be able to build a ferrari instead of first going to an automotive school or start with a motorized soapbox?

Comment: what i said is that i have questions/problems driving JSF to output class specification in appropriate HTML tags that I wouldn't have a problem with if i were using those tags directly.  that is why this is a primarily JSF question

Comment: "So you develop like going to a car junkjard, buy spare parts and expect to be able to build a ferrari instead of first going to an automotive school or start with a motorized soapbox?" -- in a way, yes.  it is how i go about ANY learning, including languages etc.  hands on, bottom up

Comment: That is the wrong approach IF you use a panelGrid and classes end up where they end up. Then work with that. But you don't always need jsf tags, you can just as good use a plain html table in many cases if you are more familiar with those. It's a choice (that can be made when you are familiar with how things work in general)

Comment: I approach it the same way, but never try to make technology work the way I think it should work (if I'm not very, very familiar with it) since that will work against me (anyone in general). But I still do not start with a ferrari but a soapbox, and in the mean time get more then familiar with underlying technology...

Comment: that's simply how my brain works because concepts don't mean much to me unless I apply them immediately.  that's why i can't read books and also because i don't have the attention span to.  some people start with the big picture and drill down into details, i start with details and puzzle them together into the big picture

Comment: I don't think the argument was ever about the learning techniques. If you wanna start up bottom then suits you. It was about using basic testing to come up with an answer of you own. If you go in a junkyard, find parts and ask someone to show you how to build a ferrari. What happens when you wanna build a BMW i8 after that ? What happens if you had one button and wanted it centered ? I ain't judging you though, we are ALL guilty of this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reason why your buttons displayed on left side is: outer table has 1 column and data in each table cell is displayed on left side (until other is defined). It means your inner table with all content will be displayed on left side in relevant cell of outer table. `rightAlign` style is setup for inner table columns and not reflected to outer table. If you want to display buttons on right side, you should change flow in cell, where button table is sitting. In following code **style** was added:

```
<h:panelGrid id="containerGrid" columns="1" cellpadding="10" width="100%">
    <h:outputText id="commentIntro" value="Some text..." />
    <h:outputLabel for="comment" value="Comment:"/>
    <h:inputTextarea id="comment" title="Comment" value="comment..." />
    <h:panelGrid id="nestedGrid" columns="2" cellpadding="10" style="float: right;">
        <h:commandButton id="submit" value="Submit" />
        <h:commandButton id="cancel" value="Cancel" />
    </h:panelGrid>
</h:panelGrid>
```

As result buttons are displayed on right side.

Comment: RELATED:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12635007/difference-between-float-and-align-property-in-css

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning a class to a cell in a nested table inside a table.
It will make a lot more sens when you will press f12 and check the dev tool because it's kinda hard for me to explain with words but basically you have no free space to align it. Like if you would have this in html:

```
<div style="display:inline-block;text-align:right; border: 1px solid red;">t</div>
```

That would do nothing because the content is surrounded by the container(notice inline-block).

The second table is inside a cell that contains a padding and then there is the padding of the cells of the second table and.. arh

Basically what I'm trying to say is that there is no free space to move your buttons. The cells are surrounding them. They are a bit on the right because of the different padding from the cells.

Your html output is like this:

```
<table id="containerGrid" cellpadding="10">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><span id="commentIntro">intro</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label for="comment">Comment:</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><textarea id="comment" name="comment" title="Comment"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
       <!-- here is the table containing the buttons which takes the space it
           needs and the td adjust accordingly. -->
            <table id="nestedGrid" cellpadding="10">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                    <td class="rightAlign"><button id="submit" name="submit">Submit</button></td>
                    <td><button id="cancel" name="cancel">Cancel</button></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

---

Having said that your question doesn't make much sens anymore but you will probably figure what you wanna do now.
On a side note, you will get nuts if you don't use the dev tool with primefaces especially with the menuitems, that thing is nasty.